# Custom design calendar archive

Tags: archives

I want to create a archive calendar into sidebar exactly like this site http://www.daily-sun.com/

I don't know they are using plugins or custom coding.

please anyone give me suggestion how to create this.

Thanks in advance,
Sujana

Answer (score 1):

They're not using WordPress, so whether they're using a plugin for their specific CMS or not is a moot point.

However, WordPress already includes a calendar widget for the sidebar.  And there are several plugins in the repository that do the same: [Calendar archive widgets](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=archive%20widget&sort=).

You will need to pick one and modify your site's stylesheet (`style.css`) to make it look like the archive calendar on Daily Sun's site.

Comment: is right. The default WP calendar widget, with some minor css tweaks will 'do the do' in this case.

Comment: Hi,<br />
Thanks EAMann and Scott B for your suggestion. I used WP Calendar widget but i can't do this calender look like Daily Sun's site (as dropdown year and month list). can you provide me any coding which will show dropdown year and month list into wp calendar widget.

Thanks again,<br />
Sujana